# spotify player plays old track for some moments in iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I implemented `Spotify` in my application using `CocoaLibSpotify` library. I am playing spotify songs from different pages of my app. The problem is, after I played a song then when I try to play another song from another page, it plays the old song for some moments.
This is some code sample.

```
self.playbackManager = [[SPPlaybackManager alloc] initWithPlaybackSession:[SPSession sharedSession]];
self.playbackManager.playbackSession.playbackDelegate = (id)self;      
[self.playbackManager playTrack:track callback:^(NSError *error)  
{
   if ((error || ([track availability] != SP_TRACK_AVAILABILITY_AVAILABLE)))
   {
   }
   else
   {

   }
}];
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Show some code, please

Comment: Please find the added portion.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Maybe try to set `self.playbackManager.currentTrack = track;` before calling `playTrack:callback:`

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried self.playbackManager.currentTrack = track; But it did not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're creating a new playback manager for each page of your app. Don't do this, or they'll overlap one another.

Have only a single playback manager in your whole app - that way, when you play a new track using `playTrack:callback:`, the new track will replace the old one instantly. Note that you do *not* set the `currentTrack` property directly - it's read-only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem fixed when I created a single instance for my whole application.